# kendo grid does not load data when it's published on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid

I'm filling a kendo grid from a web service, when using IIS Express no problem, but when it is published in IIS does not load data, Can anyone help me?

Comment: You will need to give some more details.

Comment: no one can help you until you show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that somewhere in your javascripts you have hardcoded the url to your controller action instead of using an url helper to generate it. For example you have something along the lines of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = '/SomeController/SomeAction';
</script>
```

instead of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = '@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")';
</script>
```

The reason why `/SomeController/SomeAction` is failing when you deployed on IIS is because you probably deployed your application in a virtual directory and the correct url is `/ApplicationName/SomeController/SomeAction`.

Obviously if you use url helpers to generate those urls they will take into account the application name.